# Xamarin Esri GIS SDK in PCL project with xamarin forms possible?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, gis

I am very new to xamarin platform, created PCL App for IOS and Android.
    I will be using Esri SDK for Xamarin.
    I have started with xamarin forms.

**Is it possible to use Esri SDK with PCL(Xamarin Forms) or do i have to create a Shared project?**

Is there a separate iOS and android Xamarin SDK ?

Please advice, i am looking for proper solution....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation? https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/forms/guide/guide-home.htm

Comment: this is the documentation for forms which is what you need i think
https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/forms/guide/develop-your-first-map-app.htm

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i did but they were like start of MAP app..but what if i already have APP in PLC...i can add? as i read esri SDK not available for PLC project....do i hav eto redo my APP in shared project?